# Key Value Error in saving changes to model values in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which uses a sign up form to create a user. The form is working fine and the user is created and with the correct values. However when I use Django Admin interface to change values and save them or save and create another I get an error message as below (To note: I just added 2 new values to the model - preapproved and active. I've made the migrations):

```
ValueError at /admin/app_users/profileteacher/4/change/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/app_users/profileteacher/4/change/
Django Version:     1.10.5
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Exception Location:     /home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 1832
Python Executable:  /home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.12
Python Path:    

['/home/fungai/pythonicness/milingual_api',
 '/home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/fungai/pythonicness/mildev/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/fungai/pythonicness/milingual_api']

Server time:    Fri, 6 Apr 2018 14:55:54 +0000
```

the error is traced to this line:

```
super(ProfileTeacher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and the model is (with a save function in there):

```
class ProfileTeacher(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Creation Date')
    user = models.OneToOneField(app_settings.USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Surname')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Phone Number')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'City')
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Postal Code')
    adress = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Address')
    nationality = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)', null=True, blank = True)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'ID Number(NIF/NIE)')
    bank_account = IBANField(verbose_name='IBAN', blank = True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name='Date of birth')
    #To enable them showing up in search. Only active teachers are shown and preapproved needs to be true to be active
    preapproved = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Pre-Approved')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Active')
    #Braintree and Milingual Terms of Service Acceptance
    tos = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    #If true will receive classes email notifications
    email_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name="Recibir Notificaciones")
    GENDER = (
       ('male','Male'),
       ('female','Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER, blank = True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Gender' )
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, null = True, blank=True)
    teacher_type = models.ForeignKey(TeacherType, null = True, blank=True, verbose_name='Type')
    cvv = models.FileField(upload_to=teacher_directory_path, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name="CV")
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=teacher_directory_path,
                                      null = True,
                                      blank=True,
                                      default='/perfil.png',
                                      )


    RATINGS = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=RATINGS, blank=True, verbose_name="RATINGS", null=False)
    #True if the profile will appear on milingual site as Public
    published = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=True)
    #Url: Teacher's Url
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name='Url')
    # True if teacher is legacy
    legacy = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    legacy_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Teachers'
        verbose_name = 'Teacher'

    @property
    def absolute_rating(self):
        return int(float(self.rating)/5 * 100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check how the current values differ from ._loaded_values. For example,
        # prevent changing the creator_id of the model. (This example doesn't
        # support cases where 'creator_id' is deferred).
        #Building_unique_url
        url =  str(self.first_name).lower() + '_' + str(self.last_name).lower() + '_' + str(int(self.user.id))
        self.url = url
        super(ProfileTeacher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you should show the data you're trying to send. basically you are sending a string where an int is expected

Comment: @EduardGamonal how can I send that data, its within Admin as specified within the model. I have no clue what its receiving as string rather than int and no seeming way to find out (likely that I'm being an idiot here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have set `null=False` on your `rating` `IntegerField`. This means that when you pass an empty value through the admin form, Django tries to save the empty string to the `IntegerField`, which then fails because it can't convert that to an integer.

Setting `default=0` on the field won't help you - this only applies when new model instances are created and a value isn’t provided for the field (even if that value is an empty string).

You have two options: either allow `null` values on the field, or add some logic to the `save()` method that checks for an empty value and manipulates it before you save, e.g.:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.rating == '':
        self.rating = 0
    super(ProfileTeacher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks that had me baffled. It also explains why it saved when all the values where placed and why when I emptied them it still saved because I hadn't emptied the ratings value. I mistakenly thought since it had a choice field it couldn't have been the culprit.